# Reduce Bootstrap list width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, html-lists

I am creating a list and styling it with Bootstrap. The HTML looks something like this:

```
<div class="list-group">
    <a href="/link" class="list-group-item list-group-item-success">Name</a>
    <a href="/link" class="list-group-item list-group-item-danger">Name</a>
</div>
```

When this displays, the list elements take up the whole page.[image: screenshot of HTML]

If not for the coloring, this would not be a big deal. How can I make the list elements stretch only as far as the text? Thanks!

Comment: try adding style `display:inline-block` to the `.list-group`

Comment: @XYZ I tried adding that to the elements but not to the `.list-group`. That was easy! Thanks so much.

Comment: Posted this as answer please accpet my answer if it helped

Answer (score 10, accepted):

try adding style `display:inline-block` to the `.list-group`

```
.list-group{
      display:inline-block;
 }

<div class="list-group">
    <a href="/link" class="list-group-item list-group-item-success">Name</a>
    <a href="/link" class="list-group-item list-group-item-danger">Name</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

As of Bootstrap 4.6, you can use the class `d-inline-block` to set the property `display: inline-block` directly:

```
<div class="list-group d-inline-block">
    <a href="/link" class="list-group-item list-group-item-success">Name</a>
    <a href="/link" class="list-group-item list-group-item-danger">Name</a>
</div>
```

See [Bootstrap's Documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/utilities/display/) on setting the display property.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `display:inline` or `display:inline-block` property to get it

```
.somethingClass > .list-group {
   display:inline-block; /* You can use inline also */
}
```

HTML PART

```
    <div class="somethingClass">
    <div class="list-group">
        <a href="/link" class="list-group-item list-group-item-success">Name</a>
        <a href="/link" class="list-group-item list-group-item-danger">Name</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

When you are using `somethingClass > list-group` it will effect only `list-group` when it will come inside the `somethingCalss` so bootstrap `list-group` class is save with own propery which gives by bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap includes shorthand responsive margin and padding utility classes to modify an element’s appearance.

```
<li class="list-group-item p-0">Something in list.</li>
.p-0 { padding: 0 !important; }
```

See [bootstrap documentation reference](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/spacing/) for bootstrap 4.0

Answer (score 0):

Use the Bootstrap grid system and enclose the list group as in example below.

```
<div class="col-12 col-md-6">
  <ul class="list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item">one.</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">two.</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">three.</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```